# SQL Server: Get data for only the past year

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, t-sql

I am writing a query in which I have to get the data for only the last year. What is the best way to do this?

```
SELECT ... FROM ... WHERE date > '8/27/2007 12:00:00 AM'
```

Answer (score 259, accepted):

The following adds -1 years to the current date:

```
SELECT ... From ... WHERE date > DATEADD(year,-1,GETDATE())
```

Comment: Yours is cleaner but here is what I had:

    YEAR(GETDATE()) - 1

Comment: That returns you a number, not a date, you couldn't then compare that to a date, without also calculating the year of that date. This would then return incorrect results for 31 Dec 2014 vs 1 Jan 2015 - which are in different years, but not a year apart...

Comment: correct. I needed to compare years by year number, so 2013 through 2014 for example as the data coming in only had the year. I was not clear in my comment. Thank you

Comment: I got an error message running this query ... "FUNCTION DatabaseName.DATEADD does not exist"

Any suggestion?

Comment: how to get it if the format of the date is in timestamp

Comment: Shouldn't we filter also for date smaller than the current year? `date<= DATEADD(year,-0,GETDATE())`

Answer (score 16):

I found this page while looking for a solution that would help me select results from a prior calendar year. Most of the results shown above seems return items from the past 365 days, which didn't work for me.

At the same time, it did give me enough direction to solve my needs in the following code - which I'm posting here for any others who have the same need as mine and who may come across this page in searching for a solution.

```
SELECT .... FROM .... WHERE year(*your date column*) = year(DATEADD(year,-1,getdate()))
```

Thanks to those above whose solutions helped me arrive at what I needed.

Answer (score 9):

Well, I think something is missing here. User wants to get data from the last year and not from the last 365 days. There is a huge diference. In my opinion, data from the last year is every data from 2007 (if I am in 2008 now). So the right answer would be:

```
SELECT ... FROM ... WHERE YEAR(DATE) = YEAR(GETDATE()) - 1
```

Then if you want to restrict this query, you can add some other filter, but always searching in the last year.

```
SELECT ... FROM ... WHERE YEAR(DATE) = YEAR(GETDATE()) - 1 AND DATE > '05/05/2007'
```

Comment: This will have very bad performance on big tables, you query will loop over every record to evaluate the year value of the date, it would be better to use a date range

Comment: @Adriaan Davel. How would you write it with daterange ?

Answer (score 6):

The most readable, IMO:

```
SELECT * FROM TABLE WHERE Date >
   DATEADD(yy, -1, CONVERT(datetime, CONVERT(varchar, GETDATE(), 101)))
```

Which:

1. Gets now's datetime *GETDATE() = #8/27/2008 10:23am#*
2. Converts to a string with format 101 *CONVERT(varchar, #8/27/2008 10:23am#, 101) = '8/27/2007'*
3. Converts to a datetime *CONVERT(datetime, '8/27/2007') = #8/27/2008 12:00AM#*
4. Subtracts 1 year *DATEADD(yy, -1, #8/27/2008 12:00AM#) = #8/27/2007 12:00AM#*

There's variants with DATEDIFF and DATEADD to get you midnight of today, but they tend to be rather obtuse (though slightly better on performance - not that you'd notice compared to the reads required to fetch the data).

Answer (score 5):

Look up dateadd in BOL

```
dateadd(yy,-1,getdate())
```

Answer (score 2):

`GETDATE()` returns current date **and time**.

If *last year* starts in midnight of current day last year (like in original example) you should use something like:

```
DECLARE @start datetime
SET @start = dbo.getdatewithouttime(DATEADD(year, -1, GETDATE())) -- cut time (hours, minutes, ect.) --  getdatewithouttime() function doesn't exist in MS SQL -- you have to write one
SELECT column1, column2, ..., columnN FROM table WHERE date >= @start
```

Answer (score 1):

I, like @D.E. White, came here for similar but different reasons than the original question.  The original question asks for the last 365 days.  @samjudson's answer provides that.  @D.E. White's answer returns results for the prior calendar year.

My query is a bit different in that it works for the **prior year up to and including the current date:**

`SELECT .... FROM .... WHERE year(date) > year(DATEADD(year, -2, GETDATE()))`

For example, on Feb 17, 2017 this query returns results from 1/1/2016 to 2/17/2017

Answer (score 1):

For some reason none of the results above worked for me.

This selects the last 365 days.

```
 SELECT ... From ... WHERE date BETWEEN CURDATE() - INTERVAL 1 YEAR AND CURDATE()
```

Comment: would be good if you could add the version of MSSQL server for which this works.

Answer (score 1):

Here's my version.

```
YEAR(NOW())- 1
```

Example:

```
YEAR(c.contractDate) =  YEAR(NOW())- 1
```

Comment: That works except the NOW() function in SQL Server. The correct one is GETDATE(). e.g. Get me records for last 7 year using the created date fied: 
YEAR(CREATE DATE) >=  YEAR(GETDATE())- 7

Answer (score 0):

The other suggestions are good if you have "SQL only".

However I suggest, that - **if possible** - you calculate the date in your program and insert it as string in the SQL query.

At least for for big tables (i.e. several million rows, maybe combined with joins) that will give you a considerable speed improvement as the optimizer can work with that much better.

Comment: It would be better if you create a parameterised string and avoid placing the value in the string itself...

Answer (score 0):

argument for DATEADD function :

```
DATEADD (*datepart* , *number* , *date* )
```

*datepart* can be: yy, qq, mm, dy, dd, wk, dw, hh, mi, ss, ms

*number* is an expression that can be resolved to an int that is added to a datepart of date

*date* is an expression that can be resolved to a time, date, smalldatetime, datetime, datetime2, or datetimeoffset value.

Answer (score 0):

```
declare @iMonth int
declare @sYear varchar(4)
declare @sMonth varchar(2)
set @iMonth = 0
while @iMonth > -12
begin
    set @sYear = year(DATEADD(month,@iMonth,GETDATE()))
    set @sMonth = right('0'+cast(month(DATEADD(month,@iMonth,GETDATE())) as varchar(2)),2)
    select @sYear + @sMonth
    set @iMonth = @iMonth - 1
end
```

Comment: This does not address the question.

Comment: Also, while loops are generally bad for SQL

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem but the previous coder only provided the date in mm-yyyy format. My solution is simple but might prove helpful to some (I also wanted to be sure beginning and ending spaces were eliminated):

```
SELECT ... FROM ....WHERE 
CONVERT(datetime,REPLACE(LEFT(LTRIM([MoYr]),2),'-
','')+'/01/'+RIGHT(RTRIM([MoYr]),4)) >=  DATEADD(year,-1,GETDATE())
```

Answer (score 0):

For me this worked well

SELECT DATE_ADD(Now(),INTERVAL -2 YEAR);

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to calculate "rolling" days, you can simplify it by using:

```
Select ... FROM ... WHERE [DATE] > (GETDATE()-[# of Days])
```

Answer (score 0):

Example: Get me records for the last 7 years in SQL Server.

SELECT * FROM Table1
WHERE YEAR(CreatedDate) >= YEAR(GETDATE())- 7

This one worked for me. Please reply in comment if that works for you.