# 12 months rolling data from previous month in sql

Tags: sql

I would like to find the total cost on provider group to be calculated on 12 months rolling average .

```
SELECT 
        sum(AEBill.[TotalCost])
        ,AEEnc.ProviderID
                ,AEEnc.Date
        INTO #TotalCostAccuteCareAE
        FROM EncDetail AEEnc
        INNER JOIN [EncBilling] as AEBill
        ON  AEBill.[SK_EncID] = AEEnc.[SK_EncID]    
            AND AEBill.ProviderID = AEEnc.ProviderID
                WHERE AEEnc.Date <= reportDate
        GROUP BY AEBill.ProviderID
```

This query only picks sum of all records less or equal to reporting date. But i want the average cost for 12 rolling months from the given month.

Comment: Use AVG indeed of SUM

Comment: What RDMS? I assume it's SQL Server..?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have a look at this question [SQL Server: Get data for only the past year](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30222/sql-server-get-data-for-only-the-past-year)

```
SELECT 
    AVG(AEBill.[TotalCost])
    ,AEEnc.ProviderID
            ,AEEnc.Date
    INTO #TotalCostAccuteCareAE
    FROM EncDetail AEEnc
    INNER JOIN [EncBilling] as AEBill
    ON  AEBill.[SK_EncID] = AEEnc.[SK_EncID]    
        AND AEBill.ProviderID = AEEnc.ProviderID
            WHERE AEEnc.Date <= DATEADD(year,-1,GETDATE())
    GROUP BY AEBill.ProviderID
```

Comment: You're welcome. Please keep in mind that this uses "one year" not "12 months" which is maybe not what you want, depending on the intended boundaries of your request. ("Last 12 months" could mean to exclude the current one)