# SQL Query Ran By Date Minus 1 Year

Tags: sql, sql-server, date

I am trying to run a query to display results between 2 dates, and then display the results from those same dates but a year prior. This is what I have-

`where (a.Invdate between '11/1/2015' and '11/30/2015')`

will eventually use parameters so it would look like

`where (a.Invdate between @StartDate and @EndDate)`

But I then want to be able to run the same query with the same date range but `11/1/2014` and `11/30/2014` instead.

How can I go about achieving this?

Comment: How do you want to run the query again? Manually or stored Procedure?

Comment: DATEADD: http://www.w3schools.com/sql/func_dateadd.asp use like this: `Dateadd(Year, -1, '11/30/2015')

Comment: Also is this mysql or MSSQL?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [SQL Server: Get data for only the past year](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30222/sql-server-get-data-for-only-the-past-year)

Comment: Google and learn about the DATEADD function in SQL.

Answer (score 0):

DATEADD is the best way to do this. also you can use the log way, to parse each datepart so:

```
convert(VARCHAR(2),datepart(mm,'11/30/2015')) + '/' + convert(VARCHAR(2),datepart(dd,'11/30/2015')) + '/' + convert(VARCHAR(4),convert(INTEGER,datepart(yy,'11/30/2015')) - 1) AS newDate
```

(I vot you + because you are new user) and please be careful next time then post a question