# How do you pull YTD data with a pass through query?

Tags: sql, ms-access-2010

I need to add a YTD date range parameter to a pass through query. In the past, I have been using the lines below to pull YTD data:

```
WHERE
  TABLENAME.PKUP_DATE BETWEEN to_date('01/01/2016', 'mm/dd/yyyy') AND
  to_date('08/02/2016', 'mm/dd/yyyy')
```

In the future, I want to pull YTD data without entering a date range. This can be done by creating a regular query with the following criteria:

```
Year([CPLD_DATE]) = Year(Date())
```

However, when I translate this line to a pass through query it errors out. I would greatly appreciate it if someone could help me with the proper syntax.

Comment: what error are you getting? what are the values present in [CPLD_DATE]? Please provide complete query and data

Comment: Is this oracle SQL?

Comment: Also, pass-through query to what RDMS? SQL Server? MySQL? Postgres? Oracle? DB2? These all carry different SQL dialects especially datetime handling.

Comment: I use Oracle, forcing me to use Oracle-specific datetime handling as you suggested. See my answer below. @Parfait

Answer (score 0):

Looks like *PLSQL* to me, thus could be:

```
WHERE
   TABLENAME.PKUP_DATE 
       BETWEEN TRUNC(CURRENT_DATE, YEAR) 
       AND CURRENT_DATE
```

Answer (score 0):

When using a purely SQL query, the following function will work. Based off a [very similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30222/sql-server-get-data-for-only-the-past-year) on SO.

```
WHERE PKUP_DATE > ADDDATE(year, -1, getdate());
```

However, this is not compatible with Oracle, leading me to the following function instead.

```
WHERE PKUP_DATE > ADD_MONTHS(SYSDATE, -12);
```