# SQL filter for past year from today date

Tags: sql

I am trying to filter data to bring back last 12 months or 365 days from current date.
It does bring back dates but as well brings back some dates from the future. Which from checking are in advance booked holidays.

Does anyone know how I can filter so it would bring only last year from todays date?

This is the query

```
FROM DATABASE.dbo.tbl_Adjustment 
    INNER JOIN DATABASE.dbo.tbldbST01_Personnel 
        ON DATABASE.dbo.tbl_Adjustment.Per_iCurrentID = DATABASE.dbo.tbldbST01_Personnel.Per_lCurrentId
WHERE 
    DATABASE.dbo.tbl_Adjustment.Per_iCurrentID = 257 AND 
    (NOT(DATABASE.dbo.tbl_Adjustment.DsId = N'0')) AND 
    DATABASE.dbo.tbl_Adjustment.AttDate >= GETDATE()-365
ORDER BY DATABASE.dbo.tbl_Adjustment.AttDate DESC
```

These are the results

```
31/05/2024 00:00:00.000
30/05/2024 00:00:00.000
29/05/2024 00:00:00.000
28/05/2024 00:00:00.000
27/05/2024 00:00:00.000
06/05/2024 00:00:00.000
01/04/2024 00:00:00.000
29/03/2024 00:00:00.000
01/01/2024 00:00:00.000
29/12/2023 00:00:00.000
28/12/2023 00:00:00.000
27/12/2023 00:00:00.000
26/12/2023 00:00:00.000
25/12/2023 00:00:00.000
26/09/2023 00:00:00.000
25/09/2023 00:00:00.000
```

Comment: Which exactly DB do you use? For example in mysql, you can use: `where DATABASE.dbo.tbl_Adjustment.AttDate >= DATE_SUB(NOW(),INTERVAL 1 YEAR);`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [SQL Server: Get data for only the past year](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30222/sql-server-get-data-for-only-the-past-year)

Comment: Add a tag for the dbms you're using. Both your question and the given answer contain product specific functions.

Answer (score 0):

Additional condition in your query will help to filter out future records.

```
WHERE ...
DATABASE.dbo.tbl_Adjustment.AttDate >= GETDATE()-365 AND DATABASE.dbo.tbl_Adjustment.AttDate <= GETDATE()

--Full query
SELECT *
FROM DATABASE.dbo.tbl_Adjustment 
    INNER JOIN DATABASE.dbo.tbldbST01_Personnel 
        ON DATABASE.dbo.tbl_Adjustment.Per_iCurrentID = DATABASE.dbo.tbldbST01_Personnel.Per_lCurrentId
WHERE 
    DATABASE.dbo.tbl_Adjustment.Per_iCurrentID = 257 AND 
    (NOT(DATABASE.dbo.tbl_Adjustment.DsId = N'0')) AND 
    DATABASE.dbo.tbl_Adjustment.AttDate >= GETDATE()-365 AND
    DATABASE.dbo.tbl_Adjustment.AttDate <= GETDATE()
ORDER BY DATABASE.dbo.tbl_Adjustment.AttDate DESC
```

Answer (score 0):

Advance booked holidays can be skipped by adding one more condition like this `DATABASE.dbo.tbl_Adjustment.AttDate < GETDATE()`

```
FROM DATABASE.dbo.tbl_Adjustment 
    INNER JOIN DATABASE.dbo.tbldbST01_Personnel 
        ON DATABASE.dbo.tbl_Adjustment.Per_iCurrentID = DATABASE.dbo.tbldbST01_Personnel.Per_lCurrentId
WHERE 
    DATABASE.dbo.tbl_Adjustment.Per_iCurrentID = 257 AND 
    (NOT(DATABASE.dbo.tbl_Adjustment.DsId = N'0')) AND 
    DATABASE.dbo.tbl_Adjustment.AttDate >= GETDATE()-365 AND DATABASE.dbo.tbl_Adjustment.AttDate < GETDATE()
ORDER BY DATABASE.dbo.tbl_Adjustment.AttDate DESC
```